# sort by element in array using jq

Tags: jq

Given

```
[3,4]
[5,2]
```

I'd like to produce:

```
[5,2]
[3,4]
```

I tried this but it fails:

```
echo '[3,4] [5,2]' | jq 'sort_by(.[1])'

jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with number
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with number
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-n` with `inputs` to access the stream's items. `[‌...]` collects them into an outer array, `sort_by(...)` sorts by criteria, `...[]` decomposes the outer array again, and `-c` makes the output compact

```bash
jq -nc '[inputs] | sort_by(.[1])[]'
```

```json
[5,2]
[3,4]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4oKrlvTEu8d)

Comment: Oh whoops sorry my example was incorrect, I actually want to sort on the second element in the array... I've updated it to make this clearer. Is there a way to adapt your solution to the updated question?

Comment: @tekumara Sure, just change `sort` to `sort_by(.[1])`. Updated.

Comment: You can replace `-n` + `[inputs]` with `-s` aka `--slurp`: `jq -sc 'sort_by(.[1])[]'`